# What's $interval mean in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

After installed Heapster in my kubernetes cluster, I can access Grafana but the graph are empty.
I can build a new graph with special value, e.g. "cpu/limits"; but if the pre-defined graph used $interval, the graph can not display; for example,

```
SELECT mean(value) FROM "cpu/limit_gauge" WHERE "container_name" = 'machine' AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval), "hostname"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/add-interval-variable/

`$interval` is a built in automatic variable in grafana , and is automatically set based on time range

the graph are empty? maybe your query is wrong

Comment: the link is broken. Also "$interval is a built in automatic variable" - it's obvious: the person asked what it means.

Comment: @WindyFields, thanks, I have fixed the link

Answer (score -2):

For future readers -

I want to add that sometimes the "group-by" "fill" option, which is NULL by default, can cause no values to be displayed depending on the resolution.

If you have a query you think should work, but still see no data, try changing the fill value to another setting that you think works (ie: none) and see if data shows up.

Grafana tries to use that configuration to fill in for missing data, and occasionally, depending on your interval and data collection rate, you might end up with oddness.